# How to generate JSON through SQL PL/JSON

Tags: plsql, pljson

I'm trying to generate a JSON from an SQL with PL/JSON

```
declare 
      customer json_list := json_list();
      product json_list;

begin
  customer:= json_dyn.executeList('SELECT DISTINCT
  A.customer_id,
  A.customer_name,
  FROM customer A
  WHERE A.customer_id = 1');
  
  product := json_dyn.executeList('SELECT DISTINCT
  A.product_id,
  A.product_name,
  FROM sales A
  INNER JOIN customer B
  ON A.customer_id = B.customer_id
  WHERE A.customer_id = 1');

end;
```

What I need is to join these two select to become a single JSON and look like this:
In a way where product is a sales key and the value of product is a list of products

```
[
  {
    "customer_id": 1,
    "customer_name": "Customer A",
    "product": [
      {
        "product_id": 5715,
        "product_name": "Product A",
      },
      {
        "product_id": 7841,
        "product_name": "Product B",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

does anyone know how to do it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing the "list" come from some table:

```
declare

   v_customers pljson_list := pljson_list();
   v_products  pljson_list;
   v_lists     pljson_list;
   v_customer  pljson;
   v_product   pljson;

begin

   for c in (select distinct customer_id, customer_name
               from customer
              where customer_id = 1) loop

      v_customer := pljson();
      v_customer.put('customer_id', c.customer_id);
      v_customer.put('customer_name', c.customer_name);

      v_products := pljson_list();

      for p in (select distinct product_id, product_name
                  from sales
                 where customer_id = c.customer_id) loop

         v_product := pljson();
         v_product.put('product_id', p.product_id);
         v_product.put('product_name', p.product_name);

         v_lists := json_dyn.executeList('select distinct a, b
                                            from lists
                                           where product_id = ' || p.product_id);
         v_product.put('list', v_lists.to_json_value);

         v_products.append(v_product.to_json_value);

      end loop;

      v_customer.put('products', v_products.to_json_value);

      v_customers.append(v_customer.to_json_value);

   end loop;

end;
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare

   v_customers pljson_list := pljson_list();
   v_customer  pljson;
   v_products  pljson_list;

begin

   for c in (select distinct customer_id, customer_name
               from customer
              where customer_id = 1) loop

      v_customer := pljson();
      v_customer.put('customer_id', c.customer_id);
      v_customer.put('customer_name', c.customer_name);

      v_products := json_dyn.executeList('select distinct product_id, product_name
                                            from sales
                                           where customer_id = ' || c.customer_id);
      v_customer.put('products', v_products.to_json_value);

      v_customers.append(v_customer.to_json_value);

   end loop;

end;
```

In this snippet I used the pljson types (latest version found at https://github.com/pljson/pljson): if you are using an old version of the library, replacing any occurrence of "pljson" with "json" should be enough (but I recommend upgrading or you might have problems on Oracle 18 or newer).

Comment: And if I want to add a list of json objects within products and then add products within customers

Comment: Not sure I understand: can you post an example of the final output you want?

Comment: thus, a list within the list

Answer (score 0):

@archimede thus, a list within the list

```
{
    "customer_id": 1,
    "customer_name": "Customer A",
    "product": [
        {
            "product_id": 5715,
            "product_name": "Product A",
            "list" : [
                {
                    "a" : 1,
                    "b": 2
                },
                {
                    "a" : 10,
                    "b" : 20
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```